# How relevant is the Heisenberg Uncertainty Principle?

Tags: soft-question, heisenberg-uncertainty-principle

I was originally surprised to see that,

$$\Delta x \cdot \Delta p \gt {{\hbar} \over 2}$$

But, then I realized that $\hbar/2=5.27 \cdot 10^{-35}$. According to [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/146791/what-is-the-smallest-length-scale-ever-measured) other question, the smallest length ever measured was on the order of $10^{-18}$. Of course at that point, I bring the Planck length into consideration. It's order of magnitude is $10^{-35}$. I was quite shocked to see that the uncertainty is so small compared to this unit and our practical probing unit.

My question is this. How relevant is the Heisenberg Uncertainty Principle in the lab? Does it really limit what can be probed at a practical level, or is it a theoretical limit still? In addition, if the Planck scale is shown to be the shortest meaningful length, is having a limit on uncertainty only 5 times larger than that fundamental length really that inconvenient?

Comment: Your numbers lack units. Plug in units and typical length and momentum scales and you see it's quite relevant at e.g. the scales we have for atoms.

Comment: @ACuriousMind you'd have to provide me with the standard deviations of a typical lab experiment and/or the smallest momentum measured because I don't see how units change the apparent magnitude of a number.

Comment: In a hydrogen atom the kinetic energy is on the order of 5 eV, from $ T = p^2/2m$ we get that the typical momentum is about 7 keV/c. On the other hand $\hbar/2a_0 \approx 12$ keV/c where $a_0$ is the Bohr radius. Since these quantities are of similar magnitude the Heisenberg principle is certainly very relevant.

Comment: It is also important to note that the Heisenberg principle is neither an axiom of quantum mechanics nor a statement about measurement uncertainty. It's a consequence of the founding principles of quantum mechanics so that you can't have the equations of QM without it. It is important precisely when quantum effects are. It is not always straightforward to determine the latter though, you need to make estimates like the above, which are not always obvious.

Comment: @RobinEkman  that should be "is not a postulate" of quantum mechanics. Postulates connect observables to mathematical models. Quantum mechanics is not axiomatic, although it uses mathematics with mathematical axioms. You could turn your comment to an answer, as it is one.

Comment: Anna and Robin, I am pretty sure that the founders of QM would disagree with your claim that the uncertainty principle is not an axiom, or that it is not a postulate of quantum mechanics. It is, and it is arguably the most important new one. Sources on the Internet agree, too, for example, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Copenhagen_interpretation says that HUP is a detailed formulation of "another axiom" of QM. And various books sensibly says that Heisenberg "postulated" HUP, see http://www.abarim-publications.com/HeisenbergUncertaintyPrinciple.html Why do you find "axiom" or "postulate" bad?

Comment: @LubošMotl, the Wikipedia page says that the "incompatibility [of conjugate variables] is expressed quantitatively by Heisenberg's uncertainty principle", but I think the proper statement here is that it is the commutation relations that express incompatibility and are postulated or axiomatic. By finding a representation of the CRs you can do all of quantum mechanics, e.g. calculate the hydrogen spectrum, but just the HUP is not enough for that.

Comment: Dear @Robin, I don't think that you interpret the word "postulate" correctly. A postulate isn't necessarily a statement from which everything else is derived most straightforwardly. Even in special relativity, the postulates - principle of relativity and constancy of speed of light - are rather physical, no immediate "equations", but Einstein could derive the Lorentz transformations out of those assumptions. The uncertainty principle plays a very analogous role in QM, I would say. I do think it's right to say that the mathematics of QM *does* follow from its postulates, especially HUP.

Comment: @LubošMotl It is not listed as a postulate in here http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/quantum/qm.html , but I think listed  postulates 1 and 2 imply it. Do you have a link to a different list of postulates? Imo  axioms are a mathematical beast implying a complete mathematical set, like in plane geometry, derivable from them, whereas postulates associate physically measurable quantities to mathematical forms.

Comment: Dear Anna, I can give you as many textbooks which say that HUP is a postulate as the opposite one. See e.g. this textbook of QM, https://books.google.cz/books?id=LAoAI-k-okQC&pg=PA27&lpg=PA27&dq=%22uncertainty+principle%22+postulate+%22quantum+mechanics%22&source=bl&ots=qji9LvcFji&sig=aamiwvM0s69Gp7AzM8wKrZsaEmU&hl=cs&sa=X&ved=0CC8Q6AEwAjgUahUKEwiDqrrUq6_HAhXFtxQKHTxOAPE#v=onepage&q=%22uncertainty%20principle%22%20postulate%20%22quantum%20mechanics%22&f=false - Section 1.5: In section 1.4 we introduced HUP as a postulate of QM. But I expected some answer with arguments, not "authorities".

Comment: Concerning the axioms, there are simply no true "axioms" in physics - in the narrow meaning, it's a purely mathematical beast - but physicists still use the word "axiom" for important assumptions in physics, basically for postulates, as Robin did.

Comment: You know, the reason why I found this seemingly terminological exchange worth responding to is that I feel that your ultimate reason of not respecting HUP as a postulate is your real opinion that it could be avoided or it is not important. It is very important. It expresses what QM is new about - and the mathematical details of QM may be extracted from it.

Comment: @LubošMotl No, the only reason is that I was surprised not to find it in the postulates at hyperphysics, and had to think what postulates substitute for it. The HUP is an experimentalist's rule of thumb  in the quantum world after all. thanks for the link; ok, it introduces it as a postulate.  I will try to google for a list that will have it clearly. Clones of this question appear regularly.

Comment: @LubošMotl  Looked through second page of google "postulates of quantum mechanics" .All variations are similar to the hyperphysics list except the link above. Even in your article the HUP is a derivative of the postulates :http://motls.blogspot.com/2010/08/unbreakable-postulates-of-quantum.html

Comment: Dear Anna, I know that I and many others phrase the organization of QM so that HUP is a derived fact. However, I disagree with the flat context-free statement that "HUP is not a postulate" because it implicitly says that it *cannot* be considered a postulate in any organization of the assumptions.

Comment: @LubošMotl one could think of it in the context of the usual postulate lists as a theorem from them. A theorem in mathematics is as strong as the axioms and could replace an axiom except for the requirement of simplicity.

Comment: I meant the same and HUP may be an axiom and the rest of QM follows from that. [x,p]=i*hbar really "follows" from the delta x times delta p is greater than hbar/2. A nonzero commutator between observables is the only conceivable "mathematical" reason why there could be a limit on the product of uncertainties. Within "classical plus quantum physics", it's easy to prove this rigorously.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In a hydrogen atom the kinetic energy is on the order of $8$ eV. From $T = \frac{p^2}{2m}$ we get that the typical momentum is about $3$ keV/c ($m = 511$ keV/$c^2$). On the other hand $\hbar/(2a_0)\approx 1.2$ keV/c where $a_0$ is the Bohr radius, which is about the size of a hydrogen atom. Since these quantities are of similar magnitude the Heisenberg principle is certainly very relevant.