# Smallest thing ever measured and quantum mechanic bs

Tags: quantum-mechanics, general-relativity, atomic-physics

Is it possible to prove in 2016 that the universe is made up of more discrete units than say an atom or quark? What is the smallest thing we have been able to measure, like not theorize about, but literally measure? I can't seem to find any common consensus and theories are always mixed in with the facts.

The reason I ask is that it is quite possible that what many people call "quantum mechanics" are just a collection of misguided theories about the smallest discrete unit in the universe. The more I learn about quantum mechanics the more it makes sense that people generally have no idea and are applying all kinds of formulas to satisfy something which may instead be quite basic.

And that is that the universe is made up of discrete points in space and the interactions each point has are determined by something not operating in our universe, ie a computer or simulator running our universe. It seems this is only "obvious" to high end computer scientists.

Anyone who is a decent computer scientist already knows that our universe can be simulated to a decent enough level to fool a human. You do not need to go to planck level to fool a human, even physicist humans. Provided you have enough power to run a large enough simulator you can simulate the universe to a level that in a blind test will not be found as "Fake". So why is this theory that our universe is actually a simulation, or running on a computer, not the most logical and commonly accepted one? It seems to me this occurs simply because the cross over education needed rarely exists, most physicists don't know enough computers and most computer scientists know little about physics.

String theory, multiverses, quantum mechanics, general relativity, these all seem like naive explanations of basic computing concepts.

Comment: Everything after the first paragraph seems irrelevant for the actual question.

Comment: What should the question be then in your opinion? I couldn't think of anything better, I know its vague.

Comment: ...isn't your question those things with question marks at the end in the first paragraph?

Comment: I have a lot of questions, I put the most important one in the topic.

Comment: Anyone who's a decent computational physicist knows that Quantum mechanics is a computationally difficult things to simulate. I don't see why these hypothetical aliens with computers would make their lives so difficult.

Comment: That only assumes the complex formula's involved are actually somehow related to reality at all. Whatever the smallest unit is we can find, not in theory or maths, but literally find or measure, is all we can assume that the universe is made of. If quantum mechanics or anything at all predicted accurately anything, then we wouldn't be having any conversation about what is right or wrong, we would already know. I just find it weird that anyone who is not a computer scientist thinks these theories are anyhow approaching reality when they could just be simulation sampling bias.

Comment: @ACuriousMind if it is necessary to just limit my question to the first paragraph because that is all I included in the topic then do it. It is a question I would like answered, the rest is probably not necessarily for a site like this. Sorry for any offence caused.

Comment: Are computer scientists aware that it is mostly physicists who are building their computers? :-)

Comment: Even if that is so, those same people are not programming them. If you had programmed anything of significant you would realize programming our universe is not as hard as you believe it is.

Comment: @RylerSturden Coincidentally, I work somewhere whose purpose is to write simulations of physical systems, and it turns out that this is an extremely hard problem.  So, well.

Comment: @tfb what are you simulating? Why is it hard? It is actually easier to simulate the lower level aspects of "physical systems", such as every atom, versus having to simulate it on a higher level for speed reasons. Find a bigger computer, use "atom" granularity, and you'll see your physical system "hardness" disappear. :) Of course if you are modelling large things like weather systems you can't do that with our current computing capacity.

Comment: Do you even know what general relativity is? It's completely unrelated to quantum mechanics.

Comment: Isn't general relativity a spin off company from GE? Thanks for your insight.

Comment: @Ryler Sturden At least you're funny haha

Comment: The smallest thing ever measured may be a single electron in a Penning trap: https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/255124/366889

Answer (score 5):

> Is it possible to prove in 2016 that the universe is made up of more discrete units than say an atom or quark?

Physics is not mathematics, it does not prove anything. It measures and observes and fits mathematical models to data. These models become validated as long as their predictions are fulfilled. A wrong prediction falsifies a model and modifications or new models become necessary. At the moment all our data are consistent with the quantum mechanical nature of elementary particles working within the predictions of the [standard model of physics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_Model).

> What is the smallest thing we have been able to measure, like not theorize about, but literally measure?

All elementary particles are point particles in the fits, and thus can be considered as smallest. Measurement requires rulers and clocks for simple measurments, but mathematical functions are as good as rulers and clocks , and possibly more accurate.

As an example here is a [bubble chamber photo of an electron](http://teachers.web.cern.ch/teachers/archiv/HST2005/bubble_chambers/BCWebsite/index.htm), (the helix).

[image: electron]

An accumulation of ionisation measurements  of a lot of electrons allows to identify it as an electron bending in a known magnetic field and losing energy by scattering on hydrogen atoms. All these statements are backed by mathematical rulers. The hypothesis that the electron is a point particle in the standard model Lagrangian has not been falsified up to now, with the most sophisticated experiments.

> I can't seem to find any common consensus and theories are always mixed in with the facts.

If the mathematics is correct,  models fitting factual measurements are as valid as the measurements. Physicists do have a common consensus.

> String theory, multiverses, quantum mechanics, general relativity, these all seem like naive explanations of basic computing concepts.

Considering that once people stopped counting on their fingers, geometry and then mathematics took off, it is a very naive statement, imo.  These theoretical models fit data and predict new behaviors, which is what physics is about.

Comment: Thank you for at least attempting to answer some questions. But your answers, at least to the things you quoted don't satisfy my curiosity. If you have anything further to add then please do.

Comment: @RylerSturden: If you are really curious, take a good course on Modern Physics, which covers relativity and atomic physics. It sounds like you have been reading pop science books; to actually learn you must do stuff - work problems - just like with computer systems you must write programs, etc. Otherwise all you get is a jumble of seemingly contradictory information.

Comment: @PeterDiehr yes I am not as educated as most people here on these topics. My current opinion from the broad reading of "current" atomic physics, quantum mechanics, relativity, string theory, etc is that it is like Uncle John trying to talk about computing concepts at thanksgiving dinner. Unfortunately I cannot quickly give you my experience with computers and it is the same with you giving me the knowledge on physics. Maybe if we both had each others knowledge too we could find some consensus and a better truth. I will continue to learn more about this, thank you.

Comment: @annav what you describe as "point particles" sounds to me like people think something exists because you can measure "something" happening. Imagine a 3x3x3 grid of cubes. The center cube we will call an atom. Now if we get our measuring devices we can see the surrounding cubes are having things happen to them! Why! How? We should call it a point particle because we can't see it. The simulator may be operating over each cube in the 3x3x3 grid , and changes are made based on its rules. My point, understanding changes in our universe and what is really happening can be 2 different things.

Comment: @annav there are very good computer explanations for a lot of the current "unknowns" about the universe, black holes, why the start of the universe was faster than the speed of light, why the speed of light exists, gravity, the correlation of speed and time. Of course that doesn't prove anything at all, but it would be interesting if more physicists had high level computing knowledge. I wish I had 30+ years experience in physics already! :)

Comment: Do you have a link for these explanations?  Physics theories are   predictive models of observations.  Take maps of the earth, they are flat and can be modeled with simple x,y,z coordinates. The input of spherical geometry gives  accurate predictability for the possible  (x,y,z) in 5000 kilometers. In that sense it is an explanation for why  errors in measurement appear if one uses flat geometry. Physics does not answer why , but how from a few postulates models fit obervations. It makes no difference , imo, if you use discrete variables as computer are forced to, or the continuous of maths

Comment: except to the potential accuracies.

Comment: @RylerSturden There's a [famous joke](http://xkcd.com/793/) about physicists entering new fields, in which there is some truth.  That joke is less funny when CS people are the target, I think because everyone really knows that CS is what you do when you can't hack the maths of theoretical physics: certainly that was true in my case.

Comment: @tfb Yeah I understand  there is that culture and history with approaching certain topics in physics and most subjects. Most humans have things they hold dear and will defend them, even nonsensically sometimes. But due to my ignorance in most advanced physics topics at this stage I can't really communicate my ideas properly to those who would know more than I, or argue my points in a way that doesn't make me sound like an idiot.

Comment: Due to my interest in simulations and state systems I approach this topic more like "How would I emulate the universe". The thing that evolves from us will likely be computer A.I. so it makes sense to me it would attempt to simulate universes at some point in the future, both to find the answers we are looking for, and various optimizations of its algorithms. This then makes it fairly unlikely this is the first time that has happened, and hence our universe is also a simulation. Scientists are beginning to probe certain things like "is there a time-step" like we do in our simulations.

Comment: @RylerSturden Yes, wading into probably the single most predictively-successful field in science and describing theories which have been experimentally tested to parts in $10^{12}$ 'naive explanations of basic computing concepts' does make you look like an idiot.  I am not saying you are one but, seriously, learn the field if you want to comment on it: we did.

Comment: @RylerSturden Correction to my previous comment: I think it's parts in $10^{10}$ in fact (tests of QED).  Sorry.

Comment: @tfb yes humans quite often have this issue, thinking you are an idiot because you are not educated in the same way as them, the way she goes. ;) To me a question is a question, if it is invalid I will point it out. But it is sometimes easier to just dismiss people as cranks or idiots instead of answering. I obviously need a better education on physics regardless as then I wouldn't need to ask such questions :)

Comment: @annav I do not have any good links to give you, I wouldn't mind chatting with you through email about them if you are open to it. I mainly came here just to find more info on certain questions I have about what we know about the universe to better form my own universe simulation model and to hopefully get a quicker education. I find it is often quicker to ask intelligent people in the field to help narrow down the stuff I have to educate myself on.